# How do people who say Jesus did not exist prior to his birth interpret Philippians 2:7?

Tags: exegesis, christology, incarnation, philippians, pre-existence

Philippians 2:7:

> but emptied himself, by taking the form of a servant, being born in the likeness of men.

In this passage, we see that Jesus “emptied himself” and became a servant. But this seems impossible if Jesus did not exist prior to his human conception. How do people who say Jesus didn’t exist prior to his conception account for this?